# Creating hyperledger network from UI action

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am very new to blockchain and hyperledger. I am doing an academic project and need help. I need to create a hyperledger network based on an action on website. To explain it further lets say there is a stock exchange website (NYSE). When a company registers on this website for IPO they provide information like number of shares and share price. When they hit submit, website need to connect with hyperledger and create a new network. so far every company registered on website, there will be a new network. So far I have been creating a network from command line using 'yo hyperledger-composer' command and then deploying from command line only.  How do I create one from a website?

Answer (score 0):

When you type  'yo hyperledger-composer', you don't create a network. You just create a few text files to get you started with development. In order to create a network, you have to start various nodes on different computers, and then deploy your code to these nodes. I doubt that you can do it with a click of a button on a website.

What you can do is create a channel within an existing network. This will give you an isolated "network", but you won't have to start nodes and deploy code.

Answer (score 0):

What I meant was I am starting creation of a business network in hyperledger  composer with yo command. I using following tutorial

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/ultimate-end-to-end-tutorial-to-create-an-application-on-blockchain-using-hyperledger-3a83a80cbc71

Below commands are deploying my .bna files on my machine.

$ composer runtime install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --businessNetworkName test-bank

$ composer network start --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --archiveFile test-bank@0.0.1.bna --file networkadmin.card

How do I install it on other machines and connect them. Do all the machines needs to have hyperledger composer. If I take hypersledger's perishable-network demo, there are 3 participants grower, shipper and importer, where all I need to install my network code. There are going to be many growers, many shippers and many importers. does this mean I have to install my .bna on every machine. what is the purpose of REST apis if I need to install it on every machine?